# ImageView constrained to bottom renders in top

Tags: ios, flutter, storyboard

I am trying to customize the splash screen of a flutter app on iOS.

The splash screen contains a centered image, which renders as expected, and a bottom image, which is rendered in the top of the screen, despite the fact that is configured to be shown at the bottom.

This is my view with its constraints:

[image: Splash view with its views and constraints]

The conflicting view is the SplashAppBlaze view. Despite having its bottom aligned with the bottom guide, the view is shown always at the top of the splash screen.

What should I do so the view is aligned to the bottom?

Comment: You need more constraints. The system needs to be able to work out the height of the image, but you don't have a top or height constraint. You should also constrain the width or leading/trailing edges.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm adding a bottom constraint, isn't it sufficient? Which additional constraints do I need?

Comment: You need enough constraints so that autolayout can determine the position and size of all elements. Some elements have an intrinsic size. Some some do not. For images you need enough constraints for it to work out the size you want. You don't get log messages from the launch screen because code isn't running but if you were to use this layout in your actual app you would get warnings about ambiguous layout. I am surprised you aren't getting these in the layout inspector.